# MS Access How to make composite primary keys

Tags: ms-access, database-design, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have come across a question concerning Composite Primary keys in MS Access.
I do have two tables, **tblDevices** and **tblParameter**.

**tblDevices** has two attributes:

- numDevice_TAN (aka article number; it's a number) and
- numDevice_SN (serial number, it is a number as well).

**tblParameter** has the followign attributes:

- ID (autoincrement) is the Primary key
- idDevice_TAN (number)  should be a foreign key
- idDevice_SN (number)  should be a foreign key
- boolValidity (bool)
- datStart_time (Date)
- (...)

Now here is my problem: to identify any device, I need the combination of TAN   and SN. But the problem is that there can be duplicates of the TAN number so I   have to set the "indexed" Parameter to Yes(with duplicates) and the SN   number to Yes(without duplicates).
If I set the foreign key (numDevice_SN 1:n idDevice_SN) for the SN number, it   works completely fine, but I cannot set the foreign key for the TAN number   (numDevice_TAN 1:n idDevice_TAN) because there can be duplicates.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoid compound primary key whenever possible. You can use autonumber as the PK/FK to link associated records but use both the TAN and SN fields in queries to filter and sort. Can set the two fields as compound index in tblDevices to prevent duplicate pairs. So save tblDevices autonumber PK as FK in tblParameters and don't save TAN and SN.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a misunderstanding on your side. You are talking about an index on `numDevice_TAN` and an index on `numDevice_SN`, but what you really want is a foreign key on the combination of the two.

You say that you need both `numDevice_TAN` and `numDevice_SN` to identify a device. So none of the columns alone is unique in the table `tblDevices`; both can have duplicates. You make the two columns the primary key. (SElect both columns, right click, select "Primary Key".) So the table only consists of the two fields that are the primary key so far.

The records in table `tblParameter` reference the records in table `tblDevices`. So you need both columns `numDevice_TAN` and `numDevice_SN` in `tblParameter`, too. You could use the two plus some running number for a primary key here, but you decided to work with a technical ID instead. That's okay. In any way you build the foreign key on the combined coloumns (in MS Access's relation tab: select both columns in `tblDevices` and drag drop to `tblParameter`. Make the fields match and click "referential integrity").